# How to adjust Material UI Tooltip font size?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

I implemented a tooltip with Material UI but the `fontSize` is too small. And I can't change it with a `.scss`.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./InfoTooltip.scss";
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Info';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';

const InfoTooltip: React.FC<{ children?: any }> = ({ children }) => {
  const [label, ...rest] = children;
  return (
    <div className="info-tooltip-container">
      <div className="label-container">
        <Tooltip title={label}>
          <InfoIcon style={{ fontSize: '24px' }} />
        </Tooltip>
      </div>
      {rest}
    </div>
  );
};

export default InfoTooltip;
```

```css
.info-tooltip-container {
  .label-container {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  label {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

[https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tooltip/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNALW.png)

Comment: Add a selector ID to the tooltip and use it in the css sheet, I am unable to reproduce from your code.

Comment: Have you tried adding `!important` once?

Comment: @Zuckerberg `!important` is not need because issue can be fixed without using this, this should be the last option for the issue!.

Comment: Have tried adding `classes` attribute of `Tooltip` ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can add a customized component directly to props **title**.

If needed, you can add whatever `inline-styles` to the component you just added.

Include the `font-size`

```
<Tooltip title={<h1 style={{ color: "lightblue" }}>title</h1>}>
  <InfoIcon />
</Tooltip>
```

[image]

---

Refer: MUI tooltip document: [customized-tooltips](https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/#customized-tooltips)

Comment: Beautiful answer s2

Answer (score 15):

You can do that at **global level** or at **component level**.

#### Global level

This way all the `Tooltip`s in the application will get the style.

First you need to create a `theme.js` file:

```js
'use strict';

import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiTooltip: {
            tooltip: {
                fontSize: "1em",
            },
        },
    },
});

export default theme;
```

Then import it in your main application component, so it will be applied to all the application components:

```js
'use strict';

import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import theme from 'theme.js';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <CssBaseline />
                    {/* Your app content */}
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

#### Component level

With this approach you can define a different style for each component.

```js
'use strict';

import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    tooltip: {
      fontSize: "1em",
    },
});

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    const classes = useStyles();

    render() {
        return (
            <Tooltip classes={{tooltip: classes.tooltip}} />
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `Typography` and set the `fontSize` directly. Some components like `Box` or `Typography` inherit [system props](https://mui.com/components/typography/#system-props) which allow you to change the styling using the top-level props:

```
<Tooltip title={<Typography fontSize={30}>title</Typography>}>
  <IconButton>
    <DeleteIcon />
  </IconButton>
</Tooltip>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 9):

## Using **MUI v5**

This will change the font size for all tooltips within `<ThemeProvider>`

```
import React from "react";
import { createTheme, CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material';

const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiTooltip: {
            styleOverrides: {
                tooltip: {
                    fontSize: '1em'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

export default function App() {
    return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        {/* Your app content */}
        <CssBaseline />
    </ThemeProvider>;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

another option which does not listed here is using the `slotProps` prop.

```
 <Tooltip
  ...
  slotProps={{ tooltip: { sx: { fontSize: '0.9em' } } }}
>
 ...
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import import React from 'react'
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';

   const App= () => {
    <Tooltip title={<p style={{ fontSize: "15px", margin: "0", padding: "0" 
         }}>I'm Hovered</p>} arrow>
       <div>Your Text or Element</div>
    </Tooltip>
   }
 export default App
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).